# Filter sharepoint content

Tags: sharepoint

I need to filter the content in all the pages according to user selections. there should be one control to select different parameters like country, branch and location. page content should change according to user selected values throughout site even user navigate to other pages or subsites.  When user closes his/her browser and comes back he/she has to see the content according to most recent selections.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is pretty vague; are you filtering on metadata fields of documents? List items?  What are you trying to do specifically, and what "page content" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

There are no out of the box components that will help you do exactly what you want. The closest you can get to is using the Audience Targeting feature. Kept to simple scenarios, this feature can provide a lot of mileage.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing a custom webpart/feature for sharepoint.  Depending on your policy at work the last part may not be possible to implement.

> When user closes his/her browser and comes back he/she has to see the content according to most recent selections.